# AgGrid date sorting not sorting by month, day and year. Only by year in most scenarios

Tags: ag-grid

I have been digging into using comparators and just using the date values and haven't had any luck.  I noticed all of the examples on the Row Sorting page also don't work.  Is there a known bug or workaround to sort dates with or without times?
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/

Answer (score 0):

I think the examples can be updated with this comparator functionality to be able to sort a date with time

```
   function dateComparator(date1, date2) {
    var date1Number = convertDateToNumber(date1);
    var date2Number = convertDateToNumber(date2);
    if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (date1Number === null) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (date2Number === null) {
      return 1;
    }
    return date1Number - date2Number;
  }

  function convertDateToNumber(date) {
    if (!date) {return null}
    return new Date(date).getTime()
  }
```